# Type theory: type kinds

Tags: scala, haskell, types, programming-languages, type-theory

I've read a lot of interesting things about type kinds, higher-kinded types and so on. By default Haskell supports two sorts of kind:

- Simple type: `*`
- Type constructor: `* → *`

Latest GHC's language extensions [ConstraintKinds](http://blog.omega-prime.co.uk/?p=127) adds a new kind:

- Type parameter constraint: `Constraint`

Also after reading [this mailing list](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/glasgow-haskell-users/2003-August/005543.html) it becomes clear that another type of kind may exists, but it is not supported by GHC (but such support is implemented in .NET):

- Unboxed type: `#`

I've learned about [polymorphic kinds](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/PolymorphicKinds) and I think I understand the idea. Also Haskell supports explicitly-kinded quantification.

So my questions are:

- Do any other types of kinds exists?
- Are there any other kind-releated language features?
- What does `subkinding` mean? Where is it implemented/useful?
- Is there a type system on top of `kinds`, like `kinds` are a type system on top of `types`? (just interested)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, other kinds exist.  The page [Intermediate Types](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/IntermediateTypes) describes other kinds used in GHC (including both unboxed types and some more complicated kinds as well).  The Ωmega language takes higher-kinded types to the maximum logical extension, allowing for user-definable kinds (and sorts, and higher).  [This page](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/KindSystem) proposes a kind system extension for GHC which would allow for user-definable kinds in Haskell, as well as a good example of why they would be useful.

As a short excerpt, suppose you wanted a list type which had a type-level annotation of the length of the list, like this:

```
data Zero
data Succ n

data List :: * -> * -> * where
  Nil   :: List a Zero
  Cons  :: a -> List a n -> List a (Succ n)
```

The intention is that the last type argument should only be `Zero` or `Succ n`, where `n` is again only `Zero` or `Succ n`.  In short, you need to introduce a new kind, called `Nat` which contains only the two types `Zero` and `Succ n`.  Then the `List` datatype could express that the last argument is not a `*`, but a `Nat`, like

```
data List :: * -> Nat -> * where
  Nil   :: List a Zero
  Cons  :: a -> List a n -> List a (Succ n)
```

This would allow the type checker to be much more discriminative in what it accepts, as well as making type-level programming much more expressive.

Answer (score 10):

Just as types are classified with kinds, kinds are classified with sorts.

[Ωmega programming language](http://code.google.com/p/omega/) has a kind system with user definable kinds at any level. (So says its wiki. I think it refers to the sorts and the levels above, but I am not sure.)

Answer (score 10):

There has been a proposal to lift types into the kind level and values into the type level. But I don't know if that is already implemented (or if it ever will reach "prime time")

Consider the following code:

```
data Z
data S a 

data Vec (a :: *) (b :: *) where
  VNil  :: Vec Z a 
  VCons :: a -> Vec l a -> Vec (S l) a
```

This is a Vector that has it's dimension encoded in the type. We are using Z and S to generate the natural number. That's kind of nice but we cannot "type check" if we are using the right types when generating a Vec (we could accidently switch length an content type) and we also need to generate a type S and Z, which is inconvenient if we already defined the natural numbers like so:

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat
```

With the proposal you could write something like this:

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat

data Vec (a :: Nat) (b :: *) where                                              
  VNil  :: Vec Z a
  VCons :: a -> Vec l a -> Vec (S l) a
```

This would lift Nat into the kind level and S and Z into the type level if needed. So Nat is another kind and lives on the same level as *.

Here is the presentation by Brent Yorgey

[Typed type-level functional programming in GHC](http://vimeo.com/15480577)

Comment: Update: ghc 7.4.1 supports this through the PolyKinds and DataKinds extensions.